# Javascript location.href changes page title

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a web-app and in order to run an animation before changing html pages,  tags have no href but instead have an onclick that refers to a javascript function. So for example,

`<a class='class1 class2' onclick="transition('homepage')"> Home Page </a>`

will refer to

```
function transition(page) {
    $('#transition').slideDown(); #animation
    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = page }, 500)
}
```

Everything works fine. The animation runs for 1/2 a second and then javascript redirects to root/page.
The issue is if the current page has title 'Website: Current Page', and the home page has title 'Website: Home Page', location.href will display something in between. In particular, the title will behave as follows:

'Website: Current Page' --> 'root/page' --> 'Website: Home Page'

Is there any way I can avoid having the title change twice and go directly from 'Website: Current Page' to 'Website: Home Page'?

Sorry for the long post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure the target page has a `<title>` attribute with the desired title in its HTML. Sounds like currently it sets the title later via Javascript.

Comment: All target pages already have a <title> tag with something inside.

Comment: Is `root/page`  a redirect to the home page, or is `root/page` the actual home page?

Comment: I think it's the actual home page. The app is run with flask. So for example on my local computer it would redirect to http://127.0.0.1:5000/page and when I push to heroku, it would redirect to https://mywebsite.com/page. In the case of the home page, it would redirect to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ and https://mywebsite.com/.

Comment: How does it redirect?

Comment: It redirects via location.href = page. So I suppose javascript will change your address to root/page. I am not sure if that is the answer your are looking for. Let me know.